# Calculate how many months old in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

I'm creating a child check-in system and I need to work out how many months old children are. This is quite easy however I only want to extract children who's "month birthday" it is.

What I mean by "month birthday" is if they were born on November 23, then December 23 would be their 1 month old birthday. January 23 would their 2 month old birthday. And so on...

Now my code below tells me how many months old they are but not whether it's their "month birthday".

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT('2011-11-23', '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(birthday.meta_value, '%Y%m') ) AS months 
        FROM $db->members AS m
        JOIN $db->members_meta AS birthday ON birthday.member_id = m.id AND birthday.meta_key = 'birthday' AND birthday.meta_value != '' 
        WHERE AND m.deleted = 0
        GROUP BY m.id
```

I guess we'd need to take into account if they are born on leap years (29th Feb), 30th and 31st of months too. I found this code that works for find out thei

```
(
    2012 % 4 <> 0
    OR (
        2012 % 100 = 0
        AND 2012 % 400 <> 0
    )
)
AND '11-23' = '03-01' // 11-23 is the current month and day
AND DATE_FORMAT(birthday.meta_value, '%m-%d') = '02-29'
```

Comment: So if I was a "leap baby" and born on the 28th of February, what date would be my first "month birthday"?

Comment: The 28th of each month would be their "month birthday". Same with 29th. If they were born on the 30th or 31st then it would be whatever the last day of the month is. So in February's case it would be 28th or 29th.

Comment: One last corner case - if I was born on the 30th of December (i.e. not the last day of the month) what would be my "month birthday" in February? Should I subtract one day from the last day in February?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below is complete and tested.  It should work for you if you want the ids of all who have a month bday today.

Note that you have to know whether today is the last day of the month, and you have to know whether they were born on the last day of the month.

Assuming you have an `id` column, this should do it for you.  I have tested this query, and I believe it does what you want.  If not, please leave a comment so I can understand better your requirements.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM $db->members AS m
JOIN $db->members_meta AS birthday 
ON birthday.member_id = m.id 
AND 
birthday.meta_key = 'birthday' 
AND 
birthday.meta_value != '' 
WHERE 
(
-- If it's a match, it's a match
DATE_FORMAT(birthday.meta_value, '%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2011-11-23', '%d') 
OR 
IF
(
  -- If today is the last day of this month, we want to close out the month.
  DATEDIFF(LAST_DAY('2011-11-23'), '2011-11-23') = 0, 
  -- Match all birthdays that have a day greater than today.
  DATE_FORMAT(birthday.meta_value, '%d') > DATE_FORMAT('2011-11-23', '%d'),
  0
)
OR
)
AND 
m.deleted = 0
GROUP BY m.id
;
```

Comment: you're close, but based on the above, if I was born on the 30th of December then there would be no day in February that would be my "month birthday".

Comment: Please review the second set of parentheses in the WHERE clause.  If you were born on the 30th, the 29th of February (equal to the last day of February) will match your day (greater than 29).  Did you actually run this SQL?  I tested it, and I believe it works.

Comment: I haven't tested it, just eyeballed it, apologies if I'm misreading this but if what you're saying is the case, if my birthday is the 30th won't this mean that every day in February is considered a valid match, since no day in Feb is greater than 30?

Comment: For a moment, that's what I thought too, but the code only matches three cases:  1.  the day is a match, 2.  today is the last day of the month, 3.  the birthday is the last day of the month.|-----|

You are asking about case 3, when the birthday is the last day of the month (say June 30).  Case 3 yields no matches at all in February for a June 30 birthday.  But on Feb 28 (or 29), Case 2 yields a match for June 30 since 30 is greater than 28 (or 29).|-----|

I'm still thinking my query works.  And I did test it.

Comment: I think the difficult case is when your birthday is NOT the last day of the month but the day is greater than the number of days in the month for which you are checking

Comment: If I interpret you correctly, you are asking about the case where bday = February 19 and today = December 30.  We agree that's not a match and today is not your month bday, right?  So we go to my query, and we check the three cases.  Case 1: not equal, so not a match.  Case 2: today isn't Dec 31, so not a match.  Case 3: bday is not Feb 28/29, so not a match.  The query is correct.  Did I understand you right?

Comment: You are correct on that case. Last one, I promise: b'day = 29th Feb, wouldn't both 30th and 31st of March trigger case 3?

Comment: Right.  If bday = Feb 29, then both March 30 and 31 are your month bday.  That's an oversight, alright.  Let's see.  We presumably only want the first one to be the match.  It sounds to me like we don't want case three.  Right?

Comment: p.s.  Thanks for persisting to dog that nagging feeling.

Comment: Tom, I think that might just do it!

Answer (score 1):

So to determine whether or not a given date is a child's "month birthday" we need to check that either the day of the month matches exactly, or that if the day of the birth month is greater than the last day of the month we are querying for, we check that our date matches the last day of the month in which we are checking, MINUS the number of days between the birth date and the last day of the birth month!

This last bit might sound crazy, but I think it gets you around the possibility of having more than one "month birthday" in a month that has less days than your birth month (see my second comment on the question above).

I'd be looking something along these lines, excuse the syntax, I don't have MySQL database handy:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM $db->members AS m
JOIN $db->members_meta AS birthday ON (
    birthday.member_id = m.id AND 
    birthday.meta_key = 'birthday' AND 
    birthday.meta_value != ''
)
WHERE DAY(birthday.meta_value) = 
    CASE
        WHEN (DAY(birthday.meta_value) > DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))) THEN
            LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - DATEDIFF(birthday.meta_value, LAST_DAY(birthday.meta_value))
        ELSE 
            DAY(CURDATE())
    END CASE
```

Note that I don't actually care whether it's a leap year or not.